# Page renders IE6, IE8 but not IE7?

Tags: xhtml, internet-explorer-7, rendering

I have constructed this page: http://www.letstalkmarketing.co.uk/print

It works fine in IE6 and IE8 but doesn't seem to render anything below the red help and advice block in IE7.

I cannot see what is wrong and frankly without Firebug (Firebug Lite just doesn't really cut it) I am struggling to figure it out.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you check that the page validates with the W3C Validator? Have you tried stripping out parts of the code to see if you can find something that triggers the problem? Have you tried IE8's IE7-compatibility-mode? If it does the same there, you can use IE's developer tools to help you. (still not as good as Firebug, but better than nothing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 and `position:relative` never were very happy bedfellows. Where you have

```
.info_boxes {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
```

You would probably do better with

```
.info_boxes {
    position: static;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a width. e.g.

```
.info_boxes {
    width: 630px;
}
```

You can map this into a ie7 only stylesheet in a similar way as you've already done with iframe_ie6.css, but specifying the IE version in the conditional comment.